# Drawing rectangle drag and drop using C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, paint

I have some problem with my code. All logic seems to be ok, but in function OnKeyDown there is error which said

> a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

And in the function OnDestroy is similarly

> expecred '{' at end of input

Below is my code, all definition i have in MsgHandlers.h

```
void OnPaint(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc)
{
    HPEN prevPen;
    HBRUSH prevBrush;

    prevPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, MyPen);
    prevBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, MyBrush);
for(int i=0;i<CurrentRect;i++)
    Rectangle(hdc, MyRect[i].left, MyRect[i].top, MyRect[i].right,         MyRect[i].bottom);

SelectObject(hdc, prevPen);



void OnKeyDown(HWND hwnd, WPARAM keyCode)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case VK_LEFT:
        break;
    case VK_UP:
        break;
    case VK_RIGHT:
        break;
    case VK_DOWN:
        break;
    case 0x43: // C
        break;
    case 0x45: // E
        EraseBkgnd ^= 0x00000001;
        break;
    case 0x49: // I
        break;
    case 0x52: // R
        break;
    case 0x53: // S
        break;
    }
    //InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, EraseBkgnd);
}




void OnDestroy(HWND hwnd)
{
    KillTimer(hwnd, 1);

    DeleteObject(MyPen);
    DeleteObject(MyBrush);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot the closing bracket in `OnPaint()`, it's complaining about you putting `OnKeyDown()` inside it

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are missing a "}" at the end of OnPaint